# Из-за FileDialog зависает Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt

Когда д программа доходит этого момента, `Windows` зависает (от 1 сек до нескольких минут)

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new JFrame());
fd.setFile(getPathString());
fd.setMode(FileDialog.SAVE);
fd.setVisible(true);
File[] f = fd.getFiles();
if(f.length > 0) {
    pathString = fd.getFiles()[0].getAbsolutePath();
    save(pathString);
}
game.resume();
```

Пробовал на Windows 10 и Windows 7 (На семерке так и не развисло)

[Весь код](https://github.com/Agzam4/The-Light-2-Plus-Plus/tree/main/src)

Код, указанный в этом вопросе можно найти в `game.JLight2.saveAs()`

---

Пробовал делать засовывать это в поток, все равно виснет, но гораздо меньше:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> {...};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в другом, я не добавил задержку в поток, с обновлением заголовка `setTitle()`

```
Thread title = new Thread(() -> {
    while(true) {
        setTitle(...);
        try {                               // <- Добавил, что бы работало
            Thread.sleep(100);              // <- Добавил, что бы работало
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  // <- Добавил, что бы работало
        }                                   // <- Добавил, что бы работало
    }
});
title.start();
```

Подумать только, что так можно "заморозить" windows